# convert a part of highchart to grayscale based on the selected radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have the hex colors and their corresponding grayscale colors. I want to convert the 3month, half year and full year view to grayscale when clicked on the radio button.

> eg., when I click on Oct-Dec radio button, Jan-Sept should be
>   in its corresponding grayscale and the oct-dec should be in the actual
>   colors. Is it possible to do that ?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgj7sfhp/8/)

**Edit:** I was able to achieve the above scenario, can my code be more robust to handle all situations, like if I put a datepicker. I found a bug in my code, if i click on the same radio button, the chart disappears.

```
    $(function () {
    var grayblue = '#1D1D1D';
    var grayred = '#4C4C4C';

    dataLondon = [ 48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2];
    dataBerlin = [ 42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]
    highcharts(dataLondon, dataBerlin);
    $(':input[type="radio"]').on("click", function() {
         selected = $(this).val();
        if(selected == '3month') {
            bLondon = {};
            bBerlin = {};
            tempLondon = [];
            tempBerlin = [];
            for(var i in dataLondon) {
                if(i < 9) {
                   bLondon['y'] = dataLondon[i];
                   bLondon['color'] = grayblue;
                   tempLondon.push(bLondon); 
                } else {
                   tempLondon.push(dataLondon[i]);
                }                
            }
            console.log(tempLondon);
             for(var i in dataBerlin) {
                if(i < 9) {
                   bBerlin['y'] = dataBerlin[i];
                   bBerlin['color'] = grayred;
                  tempBerlin.push(bBerlin); 
                } else {
                   tempBerlin.push(dataBerlin[i]);
                }                
            }
            console.log(tempBerlin);
            dataLondon = tempLondon;
            dataBerlin = tempBerlin;
        }
        highcharts(dataLondon, dataBerlin);
    });
    function highcharts(dataLondon, dataBerlin) {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        colors: ['#0000FF', '#FF0000'],
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'London',
            data: dataLondon

        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: dataBerlin

        }]
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: Instead of creating new chart, use a [series.update](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update) / [point.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update) to manipulate color on it.

Comment: @SebastianBochan your solution to update the chart is actually updating the complete series not part of series, `http://jsfiddle.net/hgj7sfhp/16/`

Comment: The points update allows to update particular point / points.